# Convert string to other types

Tags: vb.net, type-conversion

I want to convert string to other type.
The problem is that I know the type only in runtime.
I don't want to use a Select case. 
Is a better way?
More information:
I want to build a form at runtime.
So in an xml I have the controls for that form with all the properties that i want to set a value:

```
 <Controls>
   <Label>
    <Text>Names</Text>
    <AutoSize>False</AutoSize>
    <Enabled>True</Enabled>
   </Label>
   <TextBox>
     <Text>Id:</Text>
     <Enabled>FALSE</Enabled>
   </TextBox>
 </Controls>
```

No my code is :

```
      For Each elem As XElement In xmlDoc.Root.Element("Controls").Elements  
         Dim oType As Type
         oType = FindType("System.Windows.Forms." & elem.Name.ToString) 'FindType is a function to return the type
         Dim cnt As New Control
         cnt = Activator.CreateInstance(oType)
                For Each proper As XElement In elem.Elements
                  Dim propName As String = proper.Name.ToString
                  Dim myPropInfo As PropertyInfo = cnt.GetType().GetProperty(propName)
                    If myPropInfo IsNot Nothing Then
                        Dim val As String = proper.Value
                       ' HERE SOMETHING TO CONVERT THE STRING TO myPropInfo.PropertyType
                        ' Setting a value to the property
                        cnt.GetType().GetProperty(propName).SetValue(cnt, val, Nothing)
                    End If
                  Next
            Me.FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(cnt)
          Next
```

Comment: "I don't want to use a Select case". Why not?

Comment: Similar C#: http://stackoverflow.com/q/811436/284240

Comment: You can probably use reflection to do this.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp: OP already uses reflection, although i would use a dictionary for the mapping of known controls and only fallback to reflection on unknown types(see link above).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [`Convert.ChangeType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08.aspx) method, which receives two parameters, the string you're converting from, and the `Type` you're converting to:

```
Dim val As Object = proper.Value
Dim targetProperty as PropertyInfo = cnt.GetType().GetProperty(propName)
Dim convertedVal = Convert.ChangeType(val, targetProperty.PropertyType)
targetProperty.SetValue(cnt, convertedVal, Nothing)
```

Comment: Finally I  had to use a Select Case,
Because some properties have "unconverted" type like BorderStyle, or Color for  Convert.ChangeType.